# Hiding the element Responsively in React

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am using Reactstrap ,and want to hide my input element when the device is mobile.I used the className same as We use in bootstrap,but the className is not working at all.Is there any way to do it similarly as bootstrap in reactstap ?

```
 <input className="d-sm-none d-md-block" type="text"placeholder="Search"/>
```

I tried the above code to hide it but it is not working,is there any way to do so?

Comment: For me I use something like `display: state ? none : block`

Comment: You want to hide it on mobile devices??

Comment: yes hiding it for mobile devices

Comment: Cool..Let me share code with you

Comment: waiting for it .

Comment: Shared.. DO let me know if this helps!!

Comment: I would suggest you to change the title of the question.It help others referring to your question. "Hide the components responsively in React"

Comment: done..thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a parent component where input is being rendered;

This is assuming you have functional react component. Same logic can be applied for Class components.

```
  useEffect(() => {

    setDeviceWidth(window.innerWidth);

  const setDeviceWidth = width => {
    if (width < 767) {
      return setDevice("mobile");
    } else if (width > 767 && width < 1280) {
      return setDevice("tablet");
    }
    return setDevice("desktop");
  };

  }, []);
```

Manage state

```
const [device,setDevice]=useState("")
```

Conditionally render the input

```
{device==="mobile"?null:<input/>}
```